# Hide the scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

is there really any way to hide scrollbar in Firefox, without manipulating the padding/margin without set to absolute, and without creating a browser specific css file, I just want to know is there any clean solution like this.

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
         display: none;
    }
```

Unfortunately this only works for webkit browsers.

Comment: Use `overflow: hidden` on the respective element.

Answer (score 0):

```
html { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

Comment: This is [marked as obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Mozilla_Extensions) in favor of just using `hidden`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't let me scroll through the page, i just want to hide it and able to scroll.

Comment: Do you need it only in Firefox or any browser? You already mentioned Firefox. There is the solution for all browser but didn't get anything yet in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trick 
add a parent to your elements with this style

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

this trick send the scrollbar out of the view , it's exist but user didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the content is less than the size of the window, usually Firefox will hide the scroll.
The problem that happens sometimes is that if the size of the content changes for any reason or the size of the window changes to the content, the scroll bar will reappear and cause a mutation in the page.
If you want the scroll to always be visible in Firefox, you can use the following command

```
html  {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```